# Migration of JSF Primefaces and EJB application which interacting to Documentum content server to Spring boot and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, documentum-dfc

We have one application which is build on JSF Primefaces and EJB. Which communicate to Documentum content server and get the object. Also Authenticate the user by using IDF session.

Now the same application we need to migrate using Angular as fronend and Spring boot as backend. here Spring boot has to communicate to the Documentum and connect the server and get the object or search object.

Can any one help here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the DFC functionality with Documentum REST services. Otherwise you'll need to include DFC libraries in your application and "copy" the old code

Comment: I do not want to use Documentum rest service ... i want to use Spring Security to validate the user and Create JWT token out of it and when ever user will sent request it has the user name from that get the DFC session and connect the documentum server. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can create a session with a superuser account and then impersonate another user by using IDfSession.getLoginTicketForUser(string username). You can use this login ticket to impersonate a user by name, and perform operations on their behalf.